# Is there any available panel to store machine learning models and their config files in a structured manner?

Tags: machine-learning, devops

Saving different models with their corresponding config files, tracking the results and parameters, searching among them using customized filters and maybe always having a pointer to the current SOTA can be quite time-saving.

I couldn't even find something similar to TensorFlow Hub on the local server. Right now, closest I could get is Git LFS.

Is there anything better out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. A few open source projects are trying to do the job. The first one is named [Data Science Version Control or DVC](https://github.com/iterative/dvc). Which according to the docs is:

> 1. simple command line Git-like experience. Does not require installing and maintaining any databases. Does not depend on any proprietary online services;
> 2. It manages and versions datasets and machine learning models. Data is saved in S3, Google cloud, Azure, Alibaba cloud, SSH server, HDFS or even local HDD RAID;
> 3. It makes projects reproducible and shareable, it helps to answer the question: "how the model was built";
> 4. It helps manage experiments with Git tags or branches and metrics tracking;

The other possible solution to think of is [MinIO](https://github.com/minio/minio) which is an object storage server

> suited for storing unstructured data such as photos, videos, log files, backups and container / VM images.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Azure has a service called Azure Machine Learnig service that does exactly this, but goes much further with governance/model explainability/DevOps etc.  We also include free tiers to a lot of services and announced unlimited private repos on GitHub recently.